# change Windows 10 drag files (icon size)

Tags: windows-10, icons, cursor, drag-and-drop, resizing

When I drag a file to move to a folder in Windows 10, the icon that shows is so large that it hides the folder name.  I want to know how can I re-size the icon that shows, or remove it altogether? (I tried the Folder Option "always show icons and not thumbnails, but its not related).

I need to remove it or at least make it transparent.

[image: example of drag]

Comment: Only option that I can think of is to set a smaller icon (24x24 or 32x32) on a per-file type basis. Set the icon in the "DefaultIcon" registry key for that ProgID. Which player are you using? May be I can make up a 24x24 icon and upload it for you.

Comment: no, it's not just the player or audio files.. its is the default behavior for any file during drag and drop.. when moving files or folders or anything, they are the same huge size like the screenshot.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. But the only way to do this (to my knowledge) is to assign a small icon for that file type. This has to be done for each file type separately. Unfortunately, there is no setting to reduce the icon/thumb size globally.